# How do I pass a custom field as parameter while updating list using webservice

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a custom list called projectlist. I want to update this list with some value thru webservice based on condition, like update projectlist column say project completedDate where projectname="Sharepoint" and Status="Completed".

To update this list I have used the following technique which I got from the msdn site:

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
System.Xml.XmlElement elBatch = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");
elBatch.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
elBatch.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1");
elBatch.SetAttribute("ViewName", projectlistviewName);

string strBatch = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>" +
"<Field Name='ID'>" +RowID + "</Field>" +
"<Field Name='ProjectCompletedDate'>ProjectCompletionDatevalue</Field></Method>" +
"<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'><Field Name='ID' >" +RowID + "</Field>" +
"<Field Name='ProjectDescription'>"Project Description Value"</Field></Method>"; 

elBatch.InnerXml = strBatch;
XmlNode nreturn = ListReference.UpdateListItems("projectlist", elBatch);
```

The above method updates the list item based on RoWId, but to update the list item based on custom field like projectname or Status field (if I replace the ID field with any custom field), I am getting this error:

**"The URL provided contains an invalid Command or Value. Please check the URL again."**

My objective is to update the list item where projectname="Sharepoint" and Status="Completed".

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you have to provide the item ID - wherever you are getting row id from - try and get the item ID - otherwise you may have to build a custom service method that filters the data out.
regards,
KS